# cron.schedule doesn't send the function sendApod()

Tags: javascript, api, cron, discord.js

So i'm having this problem, i'm trying to make a discord.js bot sent the NASA Astronomy picture of the day every day at 2PM to a specific channel, and it worked with setIntervenal, but once i switched to cron it simply refuses to work.

Here's the code snippet:

```
async function sendApod() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(
            `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${api.NASA_API_KEY}`
        );

        // Create a Discord message embed with the APOD data
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(response.data.title)
            .setImage(response.data.url)
            .setDescription(response.data.explanation)
            .setColor('2f31363136');

        // Send the message to the desired Discord channel
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID);
        channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

// Create a cron job that will run the sendApod function at 2 PM every day
cron.schedule('0 14 * * *', sendApod);
```

Can someone help me figure it out? cheers!

I thought it could be a one off error, so i tried changing the minutes etc. but still nothing happened.

Comment: If your bot is hosted on a remote server, make sure you check the current time on it with `date` in the console. It could be in a different time zone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.